# Nested __try __except inside exception filter function

Tags: msvcrt, seh

Is it officially documented anywhere is it permitted to use nested SEH inside exception filter?

I'm talking about this:

```
__try {
  buggy_function_1();
} __except(filter_function()) {
  // ...
}
```

and

```
int filter_function() {
  __try {
    buggy_function_2();
  } __except(...) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not C .

Comment: so what language is it?

Comment: You use it, you should know!

Comment: Did you mean something special by saying "this is not c"? If no then you just wrong.

Comment: It is a MicroSoft "extention" to 'C'... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zazxh1a9.aspx

Comment: Yes, there are some extensions of C language, some of them are from Microsoft, some of them are from GNU, some of them are from another vendors, but all these things are still 'C'.
If you want to say that the question isn't related directly to ANSI C standart i will agree, but not more.